# add JavaScripts files to the body dynamically instead of to the head

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have done enough research and have decided to move the JavaScript to the bottom of the page. 
Here is why i should do it http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

I wrote the code below, this code only can add the JavaScript within the header.
How do I add the JavaScript before the </body> of the page? I am thinking about using

The code below will adding the JavaScript to the header not the body.

```
 public static string AddJavascript(string filename, Page ThisPage)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl js = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
            js.Attributes["type"] = "text/javascript";
            js.Attributes["src"] = filename;
            ThisPage.Header.Controls.Add(js);
            //Add to bottom of the page.
            return null;
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddJavascript("myjd.js", Page);
        }
```

I like to produce something like below this dynamically. I have several JavaScript files so i really like to keep them separate.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    my content here
    </div>
    <!---javascript should go below here-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="myjd.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ThisPage.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myjd", "[script]", true)` to register it at the end (just before closing of `form` tag).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a placeholder at the bottom of your page and then use you code to add the js to the placeholder.